# Why am I getting this error? (File Not Found Exception)

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to connect to Google Calendar's API, but I am getting a FileNotFound exception. When it executes the line "new FileStream('client_secret.json')..." this error below pops up. However I have looked manually in my directory, and I saw the exact file, clear as day. What am I doing wrong here?

***An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Zach Straley\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\255Cal\255Cal\bin\Debug\client_secret.json'.***

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CalendarQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
            request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
            request.ShowDeleted = false;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            request.MaxResults = 10;
            request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

            // List events.
            Events events = request.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
            if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
                {
                    string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                    {
                        when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
            }
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi . If you're wanting help the best thing to do is add your code and the errors you're getting

Comment: My entire question is hyperlinked...

Comment: Not seeing the hyperlink

Comment: @Zach Can you tell us what the error is? Also, is that file in the current working directory of the project?

Comment: Okay I added a picture of the code in the question, now. This is the exact error, I'm receiving:   An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Zach Straley\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\255Cal\255Cal\bin\Debug\client_secret.json'.

Comment: What would be the current working directory of the project? Like is there a specific folder within the project's folder? (ie: bin, debug, etc...)

Comment: Please don't provide links to code; links expire, change, we can't see what they contain, and the search feature can't find the contents. Do not post screen shots of bad code; copy the code and error messages into the question.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll keep that in mind next time

Comment: @Zach Alright so, to be sure, you have verified that  'C:\Users\Zach Straley\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\255Cal\255Cal\bin\Debug\client_secret.json' exists? Presently, it would seem that \Debug is the current working directory as it's guessing the file is there. And excellent point by Dour High Arch.

Comment: Okay I made a lot of edits to include the code and error. Hopefully it looks better now.

Comment: Your definition of `credPath` looks malformed; you probably want `var credPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath( System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), ".credentials", "calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json");`

Answer (score 2):

Your `client_secret.json` file needs to be copied into your build directory (currently set to your bin\Debug).

If you use Visual Studio, the easiest way to achieve this is to add that file to your solution, then click on it and enable the Copy to Output Direction option.

[image]

Comment: I suspect this is his problem as well. It doesn't seem likely that he would have that file in the \Debug directory.